# how to find control MySQL Exceptions

Tags: java, mysql

basically i have a web app in java ee with MySql DB, in my MySQl i have an ID column which is unique. now if user inputed an ID that already exist in there it pops Duplicate entry 'UserID' for key 'UID_UNIQUE', i found that error code 612 is for Duplicate name in mysql. so my question is how to get the Mysql error code and how can i pass the user that ID has already been taken
here is my java code for inserting user info to my db

```
public void getData(String FName,String LName,
        HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response){
    PrintWriter out = null;
    try{
        int affectedRows;
        out = response.getWriter();
        String query = "INSERT INTO `duckdb`.`userstb` (`UFN`, `ULN`, `UID`) VALUES ('"+FName+"', '"+LName+"', '"+Uname+"')";
        affectedRows = st.executeUpdate(query);
        if (affectedRows == 0) {
            throw new SQLException("Creating user failed, no rows affected.");
        }
    }catch(Exception ex){
        System.out.println(ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you do not simply execute another query with `SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE UID=user_input` and check if the result set has any entries?

Comment: @Blobonat Because that would waste time and space and introduce a timing-window problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should catch [`SQLIntegrityViolationException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException.html), not just `Exception`. That's what it's for.

You certainly should *not* just parse the error message. It could be in another language for example.

At the very least you should catch `SQLException` and examine the [SQL error code](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/SQLException.html#getErrorCode--), although that will be vendor-specific.

Answer (score -1):

usually we use next() . with (while or if ) to clause and use the Java side to simply check if this query returned any results:

such as :

```
Connection con = DatabaseConnection.getConnection();
PreparedStatement ps = 
    con.prepareStatement
    ("SELECT questid FROM completedQuests WHERE characterid = ? AND questid = ?");
ps.setInt (1, characterId);
ps.setInt (2, questId);
ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();

if (rs.next()) {
    // Quest already completed
} else {
    // Quest not completed yet
}
```

Comment: i think it is better to use try and catch to control exception other than if statement, try and catch can be debugged very smoothly

Comment: No we don't. Usually we do atomic inserts and catch the problems arising afterwards as exceptions. Your way presents timing-window problems and is also twice as slow.

Comment: Here you can get the ID and see but I prefer to use next()                             `Statement stmt = db.prepareStatement(query, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
numero = stmt.executeUpdate();

ResultSet rs = stmt.getGeneratedKeys();
if (rs.next()){
    risultato=rs.getInt(1);
}`

Comment: i think you  did not understood the question, i asked for how to get MySql error code and how to pass the user the ID has been taken like you see when you try to register a username in gmail or facebook which already is taken

Comment: anyone know what to do?

Answer (score -1):

not exactly the way i expected but it solved my problem, thought somebody else could use it too.

```
System.out.println(ex);
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(sw);
ex.printStackTrace(pw);

String error = sw.toString();
if(error.indexOf("Duplicate Entry") != -1)
out.print(error);
System.out.println("PW: " + error);
```

Answer (score -1):

brother I'm trying to help here . See I always do that validation with php,java ..etc , I will explain it very clear . You just need to write a query that (" Select * from userstb where  FName = ' " + FName +" ' ") check if returns a value that means the FName already exist if not that means it's OK to register that . here completely simple example

```
Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
  String SQL = "SELECT * From tableName WHERE FName = ' "+FName+" ' ";

    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(SQL);
    if(rs.next()){

        System.out.println("the Name is already registered in DB ");
    }else 
    {
        //write the query to register the name 

    }
}
```